# React-navigation gestureEnabled only works if the screen is a Navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to build a modal that slides in from the bottom and covers the bottom part of the screen. I want the user to be able to dismiss this modal by sliding their finger from top to bottom.

I managed to make it work with this configuration:

```
<Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Modal"
                component={ModalStack}
                options={() => ({
                    gestureEnabled: true,
                    gestureDirection: "vertical",
                    gestureResponseDistance: { vertical: Dimensions.get("window").height },
                    cardStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "transparent"
                    },
                })}
            />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

With the modal stack being:

```
<Stack.Navigator
            headerMode="none"
            screenOptions={{cardStyle: {backgroundColor: "transparent"}}}
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="ModalScreen"
                component={ModalScreen}
            />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

My problem is that `gestureEnabled` doesn't seem to work if the Stack.Screen component is not a Navigator. In this configuration, I replaced the `ModalStack` component directly with `ModalScreen`:

```
<Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Modal"
                component={ModalScreen} // <---------   ONLY CHANGE IS HERE
                options={() => ({
                    gestureEnabled: true,
                    gestureDirection: "vertical",
                    gestureResponseDistance: { vertical: Dimensions.get("window").height }
                    cardStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "transparent"
                    },
                })}
            />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

In this case, I cannot close ModalScreen with a swipe anymore.

**Is `gestureEnabled: true` only meant to work if the Stack.Screen component is a Navigator?**